# Getting the parent node's position via xpath in xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is there any way to access the parent node's overall position from a for-each loup via xpath?

My XML:

```
<book>
    <part>
        <chapter><author>Mary J.</author></chapter>
        <chapter><author>John K.</author></chapter>
        <chapter><author>Martin F.</author></chapter>
    </part>
    <part>
        <chapter><author>Lisa G.</author></chapter>
        <chapter><author>Harry T.</author></chapter>
    </part>
</book>
```

Here's the output I would like to have

```
Mary J. - 1  
John K. - 2  
Martin F. - 3  
Lisa G. - 4  
Harry T. - 5
```

I do understand why the following does not work, in the given context, but is there any other way to have this done via xpath?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select=".//author">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::chapter/position()" />
      <xsl:text>
      </xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

or is the only solution via xsl:number, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select=".//author">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:number from="book" level="any" select="parent::chapter" />
      <xsl:text>
      </xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: So if a chapter has more than one author, they should all get the same number? And what's wrong with using `xsl:number`?

Comment: yes, they should get the same number. There is nothing wrong at all with xsl:number, I just find myself searching for an xpath solution each time I have a problem like this before I remember that xsl:number exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the chapter's position, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="/book">
    <xsl:for-each select="part/chapter">
        <xsl:variable name="chapter-number" select="position()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="author">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$chapter-number"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```